# Python Separate Data from A lot of lines

Tags: python, json, database, python-3.x, dictionary

The most important lines of Code is:

```
r = urlopen('https://api.vexdb.io/v1/get_rankings?team=35211C)
text = r.read()
pprint.pprint(json.loads(text))
```

I want to separate information in these data with some not important things, the whole data is here:

```
{'result': [{'ap': 30,
             'ccwm': -13.7007,
             'division': 'Division 1',
             'dpr': 45.5562,
             'losses': 4,
             'max_score': 113,
             'opr': 31.8555,
             'rank': 32,
             'sku': 'RE-VRC-17-4576',
             'sp': 384,
             'team': '35211C',
             'ties': 0,
             'trsp': 40,
             'wins': 3,
             'wp': 6},
            {'ap': 0,
             'ccwm': 0.827824,
             'division': 'Results',
             'dpr': 18.2665,
             'losses': 4,
```

The line I need is 'ap' and 'losses'
What is the code I should use for sepereate these two lines,
The output I want is:

```
'ap' = 30
'losses' = 4
'ap' = 0
'losses' = 4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list` to store the data "pair".

try this:

```
json_dict = json.loads(text)

output = []
for r in json_dict["result"]:
   line = "'ap' = {}'losses' = {}".format(r["ap"], r["losses"])
   output.append(line)

pprint.pprint(output)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it will giving the output [[30, 4], [0, 4], [12, 4], [4, 2]] , which is [ap, losses].

Comment: you can use `extend` [list.extend()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm) too if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Another question, Code: output.append(["team", r["team"], "ap", r["ap"], "losses", r["losses"]])         , I want to add a line of blank after each array, how can I add that, I tried \n and "\n" but it is not working.

Comment: `pprint` results pprint is not callable.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    pprint(output)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

`print` results `["'ap' = 30\n'losses' = 4\n", "'ap' = 0\n'losses' = 4\n", "'ap' = 12\n'losses' = 4\n", "'ap' = 4\n'losses' = 2\n"]`

It is not working correctly.

Comment: `pprint.pprint()`